# Identification of blue and black tower

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

Can someone help we with identifying this set?

[image]

Comment: Not going to bother to search as this is again clearly not part of any official LEGO set as it is too amateurishly designed.

Answer (score 4):

The [list of sets containing Black Brick, Arch 1 x 5 x 4](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?itemType=P&itemNo=2339&in=A&v=0&oV=Y&colorID=11&srt=1&srtAsc=A)

[image: Black Brick, Arch 1 x 5 x 4]

(or [its alternate version](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?itemType=P&itemNo=76768&in=A&v=0&oV=Y&colorID=11&srt=1&srtAsc=A)) and the [list of sets containing Blue Slope 33 2 x 2 Double](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?itemType=P&itemNo=3300&in=A&v=0&oV=Y&colorID=7&srt=1&srtAsc=A)

[image: Blue Slope 33 2 x 2 Double]

has no common element, therefore these parts have never appeared together in an official set, so this must be a custom creation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am impressed - can I ask how do you even know these 2 pieces were never together ? Is there some search engine or does it come from experience ? Thanks again and have a nice day

Comment: @Pavel The links in the answer point to the Bricklink queries listing all official sets the parts have ever appeared in. Then by comparing the two lists one can see there is no common element. So yes, there is the Bricklink search engine, additionally Brickset.com has comparable functionality as well.